# how to delete btrfs snapshot?

Tags: ubuntu, btrfs

`sudo btrfs subvolume show /` outputs

```
/
    Name:           @
    uuid:           1f0da442-cdf3-144c-a4ce-f6c06248cfde
    Parent uuid:        -
    Creation time:      2014-08-16 19:06:51
    Object ID:      257
    Generation (Gen):   30683
    Gen at creation:    6
    Parent:         5
    Top Level:      5
    Flags:          -
    Snapshot(s):
                @apt-snapshot-release-upgrade-utopic-2014-11-28_15:10:02
```

Now, I want to delete the snapshot *@apt-snapshot-release-upgrade-utopic-2014-11-28_15:10:02*.

I tried:

```
sudo btrfs subvolume delete @apt-snapshot-release-upgrade-utopic-2014-11-28_15:10:02
```

Only got:

```
Transaction commit: none (default)
ERROR: error accessing '@apt-snapshot-release-upgrade-utopic-2014-11-28_15:10:02'
```

Answer (score 10):

I have a set of 3 drives running btrfs for data (not the operating system drive), and after testing it I found that btrfs snapshots behave like subvolumes.

For example, you can create a read-only snapshot like so:

```bsh
sudo btrfs subvolume snapshot -r /mnt/data/some_dir /mnt/data/@some_dir-snapshot-test
```

Then, to delete the snapshot again:

```bsh
sudo btrfs subvolume delete /mnt/data/@some_dir-snapshot-test
```

**Be very careful not to delete the original subvolume!** It's very easy to accidentally delete the original subvolume instead of the snapshot if you're not careful. [Make sure you have tested backups](http://taobackup.com/)!

Comment: I have mounted whole drive to /home point. It's formatted as btrfs. I have my user home directory there. Few days ago I delete 70 gigabyte of data from /home/my-user/Downloads and /home/my-user/torrents. The free space measure didn't move a tiny bit. I thought that I have to delete snapshots so I did the way You provided. It helped a little. I recovered only 20GB. Do you know what is going on? How can I recover all that free space? Best regards!

Comment: @Marecky I once had a situation where I couldn't free 1TB of data because I had it mounted as a loopback device. Have you tried rebooting yet? You might also want to run a full balance: `sudo btrfs balance start -v /absolute/path/to/mount/point`.

Comment: Thanks, I did something like trim SSD and it btrfs recalculated the free space. I'm not quite sure it helped. It could be something else. I wanted to run btrfs balance but I think I made a restart and it was the thing.

Comment: I think I lost some data. Is it possible to delete data when removing snapshots? How I could recover it? What is the original subvolume? The one with id = 1? I deleted it

Comment: @Marecky If snapshots contain data that isnt' present anywhere else, then yes you can delete data when deleting snapshots. The id of the root subvolume is `5`. That would be a different question though here on Stack Exchange, but my immediate advice is **take a block-for-block backup copy of the hard drive**, and work from that.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is good answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441375/cant-delete-a-btrfs-snapshot)

The snapshot exists in the real root of the filesystem, which is not what you have mounted in /. You have the /@ subvolume mounted in /, so there is no such file with that name. You have to mount the real root volume somewhere and use that path to reference the snapshot.

Or you can use apt-btrfs-snapshot delete instead.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1092226)